# Cannot install rssh on Ubuntu virtualbox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, debian

I'm trying to download rssh on an Ubuntu 20.04.3 Virtualbox.
I tried `sudo apt-get install rssh`
That gave me `E: Unable to locate package rssh`

I looked up the error online.  I found this thread: https://github.com/serghey-rodin/vesta/issues/1681
I followed the suggestions there and tried
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get upgrade`
`sudo apt-get install rssh`

Neither of those worked, so I went into my /etc/apt/sources.list and doublechecked, and all the compiled repositories are enabled... so I'm not sure what the problem is.  My end goal is following the directions here http://www.granthurley.ca/blog/running-and-integrating-archivematica-and-atom-with-vagrant/ to try setting up integration between two servers running open-source software for Archives.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

"Unable to locate" isn't an error, it just tells you the package you're searching for isn't available in the repos. In the case of rssh that's likely because there are a number of [high severity vulnerabilities](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-2291/Rssh.html) which will never be fixed. rssh hasn't been updated since 2003, the author himself stating ["*rssh is done, period*"](http://rssh.sourceforge.net/future.shtml).

I found an alternative in Ubuntu Launchpad, [rush](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/focal/+package/rush).

Another alternative is just to use SSH to connect and restrict the user by using [rbash](https://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/html_node/The-Restricted-Shell.html) as shell, or chrooting user's shell.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the rssh package was removed from Ubuntu 20.04 focal: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=rssh&searchon=names
On the homepage of rssh (http://www.pizzashack.org/rssh/) it's written: ***Sadly RSSH died a horrible death in 2019** when it became clear that providing restricted access to arbitrary programs is nearly impossible, particularly without being extremely expert in all of the programs involved (including sshd and all of the applications you wish to restrict). This proved to be an unmanageable task, and support for RSSH ended with unpatched (and I believe unpatchable) security issues, not entirely the fault of RSSH itself.* One can still **use the Debian stretch rssh package on a Ubuntu 20.04** machine (https://packages.debian.org/stretch/amd64/rssh/download) or learn to setup **rush** as previously suggested (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/focal/+package/rush) ♥

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! While this is an answer to the question, it is not clear how it is better than the already existing one.

Comment: @DarkDiamond We'll be the judge of that, no you :-)